# NCurses chat misbehaving, blocking in select

Tags: c, sockets, select, networking, ncurses

I wrote a C application for a socialization network and also a simple room-based chat. I used ncurses, sockets and basic networking stuff.

The problem is that my function uses select() to read from server socket AND stdin so when I start to write a message, the output window freezes and only shows messages from other clients after I hit enter.

I tried everything possible .. Is there a way to fix this ?

I also tried to force nocbreak().It works okay but if I do that, when I write the message, the echoing is disabled and nothing shows up in the input window as I type, even though the message is there but like "invisible".

Here is the code :

```
ssize_t safePrefRead(int sock, void *buffer)
{
    size_t length = strlen(buffer);

    ssize_t nbytesR = read(sock, &length, sizeof(size_t));
    if (nbytesR == -1)
    {
        perror("read() error for length ! Exiting !\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nbytesR = read(sock, buffer, length);
    if (nbytesR == -1)
    {
        perror("read() error for data ! Exiting !\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return nbytesR;
}

ssize_t safePrefWrite(int sock, const void *buffer)
{
    size_t length = strlen(buffer);

    ssize_t nbytesW = write(sock, &length, sizeof(size_t));
    if (nbytesW == -1)
    {
        perror("write() error for length ! Exiting !\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nbytesW = write(sock, buffer, length);
    if (nbytesW == -1)
    {
        perror("write() error for data ! Exiting !\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return nbytesW;
}

void activeChat(int sC, const char *currentUser, const char *room)
{
    char inMesg[513], outMesg[513];
    char user[33];


    int winrows, wincols;
    WINDOW *winput, *woutput;

    initscr();
    nocbreak();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, winrows, wincols);
    winput = newwin(1, wincols, winrows - 1, 0);
    woutput = newwin(winrows - 1, wincols, 0, 0);
    keypad(winput, true);
    scrollok(woutput, true);
    wrefresh(woutput);
    wrefresh(winput);



    fd_set all;
    fd_set read_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&all);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(0, &all);
    FD_SET(sC, &all);

    wprintw(woutput, "Welcome to room '%s' \n Use /quitChat to exit !\n!", room);
    wrefresh(woutput);

    while (true)
    {
        memcpy( &read_fds, &all, sizeof read_fds );
        if (select(sC + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        {
            perror("select() error or forced exit !\n");
            break;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(sC, &read_fds))
        {
            memset(inMesg, 0, 513);
            safePrefRead(sC, user);
            safePrefRead(sC, inMesg);
            wprintw(woutput, "%s : %s\n", user, inMesg);
            wrefresh(woutput);
            wrefresh(winput);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(0, &read_fds))
        {

            //wgetnstr(winput, "%s", outMesg);

            int a, i = 0;

            while ( i < MAX_BUF_LEN && (a = wgetch(winput)) != '\n')
            {
                outMesg[i] = (char)a;
                i++;
            }
            outMesg[i] = 0;


            if (outMesg[0] == 0)
                continue;
            if (strcmp(outMesg, "/quitChat") == 0)
            {
                safePrefWrite(sC, outMesg);
                break;
            }
            safePrefWrite(sC, outMesg);
            delwin(winput);
            winput = newwin(1, wincols, winrows - 1, 0);
            keypad(winput, true);
            wrefresh(winput);
        }
    }

    delwin(winput);
    delwin(woutput);
    endwin();
}
```

-safePrefWrite and safePrefRead are wrappers for prexied read / write and error treating
-sC is the server socket.

LE: I tried using fork and threads. Using fork was behaving the same and threads were a disaster, the terminal was messed up.

Thank you.

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: " I tried everything possible ..  " -- Please state here what are those possibilities.

Comment: I will paste the code later here as I am not able to do so now. By everything I meant forcing echo(), printing character by character in winput as I read them with waddch(), forks, threads .. I can't remember them all cause this issue ate 7 hours of my life.

Comment: The pastebin code seems to be a snippet out of a larger file.  Amongst other things, what header files are being #include'd? how is the posted code being called.

Comment: There seems to be no way for the 'remote' user to gracefully exit the program.   When the local user exits the program, the local users' text input is broadcast rather than something like: '<user-name> waved goodby as they exited the room`

Comment: This is for a school project that I have to finish ASAP. Don't you think that what you said are my LAST problems ? Really. I've just asked for a solution about the blocking issue...

Answer (score 0):

modify the `while(true)` loop to only handle one char at a time for the stdin.

Which mostly means for stdin, read a single char:

if char is '\n' then handle as currently,

otherwise, just append char to the buffer to write.

Always, before appending a char to buffer to write, check that buffer is not full.

add code to handle the case where the buffer to write is full

end the function with this sequence:

```
delwin(winput);
delwin(woutput);
endwin();
endwin();
```

to end both windows.

Do not call endwin() during processing of the socket input.

Do not call endwin() when `select()` returns an error condition

the `fd_set` is not an intrinsic size in C, so use `memcpy()` to set 
 `read_fds` from `all`. suggest:

```
memcpy( &read_fds, &all, sizeof read_fds );
```

the parameter: `currentUser` is not used, suggest inserting the line:

```
 (void)currentUser;
```

to eliminate a compiler warning message.

for readability, and ease of understandability, suggest #define the magic numbers 513 and 33 with meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

```
#define MAX_BUF_LEN (513)
#define MAX_USER_LEN (33)
```

this line: `outMesg[i] = a;` raises a compiler warning, suggest:

```
outMesg[i] = (char)a;
```

This line: `while ( (a = wgetch(winput)) != '\n')` can allow the buffer outMesg[] to be overrun, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  suggest:

```
while ( i < MAX_BUF_LEN && (a = wgetch(winput)) != '\n')
```

Suggest posting the prototypes for the safePrefWrite() and safePrefRead() functions, similar to:

```
void safePrefRead( int, char * );
void safePrefWrite( int, char * );
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "modifying" the while(true) loop. Don't I already have that in the second if ?

I modified what you said but I still don't get it how to fix my code...

Comment: when reading from stdin, only input one char (not all the available characters) before returned to the top of the `while()` loop.   The only time to do anything else in the handling of stdin is when a '\n' is input.  Then, and only then, process the whole input string, including the check for `/quitchat` and calling safePrefWrite() then the I/O to the remote user will not be frozen while waiting for the local user to finish inputting the next line to transmit to the remote user.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @user3629249, there are several criticisms which can be applied to the sample code.  However, OP's question is not addressed by those improvements.

OP seems to have overlooked these functions:

- [`cbreak`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak) or [`raw`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-raw_noraw), to make `wgetch` read unbuffered data, i.e., not waiting for `'\n'`.
- [`nodelay`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay) or [`timeout`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-timeout_wtimeout), to control the amount of time `wgetch` spends waiting for input.

By the way, making `select` work with a curses program will make assumptions about the curses library internal behavior: getting that to work reliably can be troublesome.

Comment: Doesn't cbreak() make my select() set the stdin as soon as the first letter is typed ? I mean, what is the point ? I also tried nodelay() but I didn't see any improvement.

What are my options to make this work the right way ?

Comment: the posted code is using wgetch() for each input char.  The char will already be available due to the `select()` statement, so no need to 'timeout' any of the wgetch() function as it will never be waiting.   If the input is run in `raw` mode then each key stroke will be immediately available; however, then the program will need to handle all the non printable keystrokes.  This will greatly complicate the code logic. but may be worthwhile to enable faster response to input from the remote user.  And that faster response is exactly what my answer addresses (along with several other problems.

Comment: I have used `select()` with ncurses in several projects,  it works very well.  If using 'cooked' input mode, then `select()` will not be triggered by the local user entering keystrokes (however those keystrokes will be echo'd and can be edited by `backspace`, etc.) Only when the local user enters a '\n' or EOF will the `select()` be 'triggered'.  Do not call wgetch() unless the `select()` has already indicated a char is available to input

Comment: Can you give me a sample code for this ?Because as much as I'm thinking for this solution, I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it finally by using only the big loop.

Here is the code if anyone has the same problem in the future :

```
if (FD_ISSET(0, &read_fds))
    {


        inChar = wgetch(winput);

        if (inChar == 27)
        {
            safePrefWrite(sC, "/quit");
            break;
        }

        if (inChar == KEY_UP || inChar == KEY_DOWN || inChar == KEY_LEFT || inChar == KEY_RIGHT)
            continue;

        if (inChar == KEY_BACKSPACE || inChar == KEY_DC || inChar == 127)
        {
            wdelch(winput);
            wrefresh(winput);
            if (i != 0)
            {
                outMesg[i - 1] = 0;
                i--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            outMesg[i] = (char)inChar;
            i++;
        }


        if (outMesg[i - 1] == '\n')
        {
            outMesg[i - 1] = 0;
            i = 0;

            if (outMesg[0] == 0)
                continue;

            if (strcmp(outMesg, "/quit") == 0)
            {
                safePrefWrite(sC, outMesg);
                break;
            }

            safePrefWrite(sC, outMesg);
            delwin(winput);
            winput = newwin(1, wincols, winrows - 1, 0);
            keypad(winput, true);
            wrefresh(winput);
            memset(outMesg, 0, 513);
        }
    }
```

I also use raw() to disable signals and to treat the codes how I want.
Anything else above and below this "if" is just like in the 1st post.